# display images from cache folder, on new server of existing project

Tags: product-images, cache, media, media-images, magento1.9.2.3

I am trying to setup existing Magento project on the local system and new server. I copied all files of the existing project and set it up the entire project. But, no product images are showing on the front-end or back-end. It is all showing magento placeholder. How should I get product images working on front-end and back-end?

Comment: are you sure you have the images in the proper media directory? and url of images are correct in rendered html?